# Get a string and return it if it matches a regex

Tags: ruby, loops

Couldn't find a better way to write the following:

```
def get_name
  print "Please enter your name: "
  name = ""
  loop do
    break if (name = gets.chomp).match(/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
    print "Please enter your name again (must be one or more letters): "
  end
  name
end
```

How can I write this ruby method in a better way?

Comment: please add more details on what you want - better performance, this code isnt working etc..

Comment: The code seems cumbersome for an elegant language like ruby... I would expect that a simpler loop can be written, without the need to init 'name' before the loop

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I can't rewrite this if I don't know the rest of the code.

Comment: (1) prompt for typing a name  (2) get the input  (3) return the typed input if a string consisting only of letters has been typed, prompt again if not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with your code is that it's trying to do two quite different functions at the same time: validating format and handling user input. Better to separate the two. What do you think of this?

```
def format_ok?(name)
  name =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/
end

def get_name
  print "Please enter your name: "
  loop do
    name = gets.chomp
    return name if format_ok?(name)
    print "Please enter your name again (must be one or more letters): "
  end
end
```

Comment: Only thing I can add is to use `puts` instead of `print`

Comment: This regex is more restrictive than the OP's, but it is likely that the OP made a mistake.

Comment: But assuming that the standard input is probably the terminal, which means that the input cannot include newlines in the middle, your regex would actually be equivalent to and better than the OP's.

Comment: @Ekult3k: why `puts` and not `print`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why would you use `print` in Ruby? That makes no sense when you have `puts` Also why would you use a loop? It doesn't make any sense to use a loop for something, that doesn't need a loop.

Comment: @Ekult3k: "makes no sense" statement here is quite a bold one, without any foundation. `print` doesn't add a newline and this is why it's used here. Next time provide _something_ to back up your statements :)

Comment: @Ekult3k: but there's a loop in your code too, disguised as recursion.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Because it's bad practice to use print in any given situation.

Comment: @Ekult3k: again, making baseless statements won't get you very far in programming. You can have a great career in politics, though.

Comment: @Ekult3k: it doesn't do the same thing. Show your code and its outputs

Comment: @SergioTulentsev OH, light bulb. That's pretty slick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to write it:

```
def get_name
  print "Please enter your name: "
  until gets =~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/
    print "Please enter your name again (must be one or more letters): "
  end
  $_.chomp
end
```

It reads a line from standard input until it matches the regular expression, printing an error message otherwise. Upon success, it returns the chomped line ([`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) assigns to `$_`).

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide one more variation:

```
def prompt_name(p)
    puts p
    gets.chomp.strip
end

def get_name
    name = ''
    name = prompt_name("Please enter your name #{name.empty? ? '' : 'again '}:") while name !~ /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/
    name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
def get_name
  print "Please enter your name: "
  name = gets.chomp
  until name  =~ /[[:alpha:]]/
    print "Please enter your name again (must be one or more letters): "
    name = gets.chomp
  end
    puts "your name is #{name}"
end

get_name

 > get_name
# Please enter your name: 3212
# Please enter your name again (must be one or more letters): 12Gagan
# your name is 12Gagan
```

### [Demo](https://repl.it/B4tC/1)

Comment: @Stefan : yes I missed it. now corrected. but it is similar with your answer.